# PHP - "Restart" values include file in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop that calls a file through `include`:

```
foreach ($multiTradingPairs as $multiTradingPair) {
    echo '<h1>'.$multiTradingPair['pair'].'</h2>';
    include('new-trader.php');
    sleep(2);
}
```

The include file calculates the RSI and the above foreach loop basically calculates the Relative Strength Index of three currencies based on a previous predetermined array.

My problem is that the data from the first array key is being passed onto the second one, and the data from the second one onto the third. This means that the RSI is being calculated incorrectly.

How can I reset the values in the 'include' file to start it from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also include the relevant variable code for `new-trader.php` that is getting overridden please?

Comment: @ObsidianAge The code to calculate the RSI is too long. That is why I wanted to know whether I can completely reset the values.

Comment: You certainly could, but it would depend a lot on the structure of your secondary file. I'd recommend turning the `new-trader` file into a function that accepts the variable as a function parameter. From there you can manipulate as need be :)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving everything that you need inside of `new-trader.php` into a function.
Then, only include the file once, outside of the loop.

Then, while you're iterating through the array, call the included function with an argument, which is a single `$multiTradingPair`.